# When lxml.etree performs XPath parsing on the web page, it is unable to obtain all the text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

When I use lxml.etree to parse HTML, if the target tag contains multiple tags, I cannot parse all the text using XPath.
For example:

```
content = """
    <h3 id="author">
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">zhang</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">wang</a>
        </span>
        <p class="email">1234567@qq.com</p>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">li</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">lin</a>
        </span>
    </h3>
"""

from lxml import etree
html_tree = etree.HTML(content)
print(html_tree.xpath('//h3[@id="author"]//text()'))
```

The result is:

```
['\n        ',
 '\n            ',
 'zhang',
 '\n        ',
 '\n        ',
 '\n            ',
 'wang',
 '\n        ',
 '\n        ']
```

I can't get the text "Li" and "Lin", But when I delete the P tag, I can get all the text.
For example:

```
content = """
    <h3 id="author">
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">zhang</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">wang</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">li</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">lin</a>
        </span>
    </h3>
"""

from lxml import etree
html_tree = etree.HTML(content)
print(html_tree.xpath('//h3[@id="author"]//text()'))
```

The result is:

```
['\n        ',
 '\n            ',
 'zhang',
 '\n        ',
 '\n        ',
 '\n            ',
 'wang',
 '\n        ',
 '\n        ',
 '\n            ',
 'li',
 '\n        ',
 '\n        ',
 '\n            ',
 'lin',
 '\n        ',
 '\n    ']
```

- python3.6.2
- lxml (3.8.0)

Comment: If you parse as HTML then the parser might correct your markup and I think in HTML 4, which libxml2 supports for HTML parsing, both `h3` and `p` elements are block elements which cannot be contained in each other, so the `p` element might be moved after the `h3` as a sibling. Dump the parsed tree to check.

Comment: Thank you very much. After printing, I found that the `h3` was moved to the front of the `p`.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse from string, you will get the correct response:

```
from lxml import etree

content = """
    <h3 id="author">
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">zhang</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">wang</a>
        </span>
        <p class="email">1234567@qq.com</p>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">li</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a target="_blank">lin</a>
        </span>
    </h3>
"""
root = etree.fromstring(content)
print(root.xpath('//h3[@id="author"]//text()'))
```

Result:

```
['\n        ', '\n            ', 'zhang', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n            ', 'wang', '\n        ', '\n        ', '1234567@qq.com', '\n        ', '\n            ', 'li', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n            ', 'lin', '\n        ', '\n    ']
```

Comment: It works because you parse as XML, and not as HTML.